# Admobs scrolling in iphone

Tags: iphone

Hello 
I am using admobs sdk in iphone. I want to show ads in only main view. I applied UItableview
programatically and I used AdmobView in this view .
my problem is ads are scrolling with screen/tableview and ads is overlapping table's cell
How should I fix position of ads to bottom so that it cant be scroll with table.

Comment: Your code must be wrong. I tried it and it doesn't display anything.

Comment: my code is displaying test ads properly but it scrolling with screen.I want to fix this ads in bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add AdmobView to your table view's rows.

You can create another parent view that holds the AdmobView and table view. When the ad is loaded, you should also adjust the height of the table view and slide the AdmobView up.

Comment: I didn't add AdmobView to my table view's rows.I created it programmatically it is loading below the tableview.but when scrolling table it is overriding table's row.

Comment: Ok. I assume you mean the AdmobView is on top the table view, therefore overlapping it. It is not scrolling with the table as you mentioned in your post. You need to adjust the height of the table view (subtract from the height of the admob view).

Comment: I tried adjusting height of the table view.But If I used admob in single screen which has not any tableview It is still scrolling with Screen.